# How can I turn on what looks like a Lotus Notes Replication Status screen?

Tags: lotus-notes, replication

I'm using Lotus Notes 8.5 on Windows 7.  About 4 months ago, IT replaced my XP box with my new Win 7 machine.  I don't know what my former version of Lotus was, but I know it was older than the current one that I'm using.

On the Windows XP machine, if I forced a replication, in the background, another tab would appear that showed the status of my various databases being replicated.

On my new PC, when I force a replication that screen never shows up.  I don't know what it's called but I'd like for the replication status screen to open when I force a replication.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the Replication and Sync window? It's available in the left bookmark/navigation bar:

[image]

If you are using Notes 8.x you might not have a bookmark/navigation bar on the left but rather an Open button. In that case look for "Replication and Sync":

[image]